# assign a value dynamically to a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, foreach

I got a multidimensional array as result of a json_decode:

```
$start=new DateTime();
$jzon='[{"latitude":41.9089983,"longitude":12.4778983,"mVersionCode":1, "data":""},
{"latitude":41.9091,"longitude":12.4781983,"mVersionCode":1, "data":""},
{"latitude":41.9087983,"longitude":12.4786,"mVersionCode":1, "data":""},
{"latitude":41.9082,"longitude":12.4793,"mVersionCode":1, "data":""},
{"latitude":41.9065,"longitude":12.4811983,"mVersionCode":1, "data":""},
{"latitude":41.9061983,"longitude":12.4819983,"mVersionCode":1, "data":""},
{"latitude":41.9063983,"longitude":12.4827983,"mVersionCode":1, "data":""},
{"latitude":41.9089983,"longitude":12.4840983,"mVersionCode":1, "data":""}]';

$arrayJson=json_decode($jzon, TRUE);
```

then I try different way to walk through the array and the more useful I find is this one:

```
if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    // JSON is valid
    foreach($arrayJson as $cell) {
        foreach($cell as $key=>$value) {    
            if($key=='data') {
                $value=$start->format('Y-m-d\ H:i:s');
                $start=$start->modify('+1 seconds');                    
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo " not valid Json";
}
```

I've tried some different approach to assign to the field "data" the value of start but if made a `var_dump` over the `$arrayJson` object there is not setted value!

`$cell[$value]=$start;` doesn't work!
`$value= $something;` doesn't work!

Comment: Use `References` Change this `foreach($cell as $key=>$value)` to `foreach($cell as $key=>&$value)` and this `foreach($arrayJson as $cell)` to `foreach($arrayJson as &$cell)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, use by reference. There is also no need to have the inner loop, you can access the 'data' member directly:

```
foreach($arrayJson as &$cell)
{
    $cell['data'] = $start->format('Y-m-d\ H:i:s');
    $start=$start->modify('+1 seconds');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to Rome: (Using references)

```
if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
  // JSON is valid
  foreach($arrayJson as &$cell)//<--- reference here
  {
   $cell['data'] = $start->format('Y-m-d\ H:i:s');
   $start = $start->modify('+1 seconds');                 
  }
} else { 
  echo " not valid Json"; 
}
```